# Interpret / Extract location values from text in JavaScript - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

I have a string: "I would like to ship a sofa to Heathrow weighing 60lB from LAX by the 29th of November with AWB 12381140743"

I pass the above string to my Google NLP API and it spits out a list of json objects.

Looking for the tag LOCATION I am able to extract the location from the JSON object, 
however if I don't look for the previous word (i.e. to, from), I can't understand which one is the origin and which one is the destination.
Furthermore if values are inverted (i.e. from - to) the current code is not able to identify the origin and destination correctly.

```
entities.forEach(element => {
        if (element.type === 'LOCATION') {

            const index = getTokenElementIndex(tokens, element.name);
            const wordBefore = getPreviousWord(tokens, index);

            if (wordBefore === 'from') {
                origin = element.name;
            } else if (wordBefore === 'to') {
                destination = element.name;
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a better way to do it? Any suggestion or libraries that I can use? Any thoughts on how can I improve my code to better understand the text context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is, given a location (entity), classify whether that location is a `destination`, `origin`, or `neither`. Right now you have a rule based classifier, which looks only at the token before the location. You could build a classifier that has access to a larger window (say, +/- 2 tokens to either side). This is the most work, but has the potential to be the most accurate.

The easiest thing to do is use a tool like [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com/), which is a Google SaaS product for conversational UIs. You could define a ["developer entity"](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-developer) called `origin` and give examples like `from LAX`, `starting at LAX`, etc. I am not sure how much better this will be than just extending your rule-based classifier a little.

Note: [Rasa NLU](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/about/) is an open-source competitor to DialogFlow that I recommend. It's just a little more work to spin up.

Comment: re-reading this, I feel like I didn't spend enough time on improving the rule based classifier. The best advice I can give is "look at a bunch of examples. see if there are any heuristics that combined that are very accurate".